# How to import only the first row from a csv file in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm trying to make a function that imports only the first row (head) from a csv.

```
BEGIN
set schema 'public';
   CREATE TABLE table0(cols text);
  
   EXECUTE format($$COPY table0 FROM %L WITH (DELIMITER ';')$$, _file); 
   EXECUTE format('SELECT cols from table0 LIMIT 1';
```

I've tried to import all csv and then save the first row, but it doesn't work.

The error is:

> null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier

is there an option to import only the first row?

Comment: What about it didn't work?  Did you get an ERROR?  If so, what was it?

Comment: Sorry! The Error is: null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier